# NumberFormatInfo not removing decimals

Tags: c#, globalization

This should be really simple and straight forward but for some reason it won't work.

```
var myNumber = "100255.123";

var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo
{CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0, NumberDecimalDigits = 0, PercentDecimalDigits = 0};

var noDecimals = decimal.Parse(myNumber, numberFormatInfo);

//noDecimals = 100255.123 ???
```

For context reasons I do need to parse this string as a decimal and not an integer.

Shouldn't the "noDecimals" variable be parsed as "100255" without any decimal digits after applying the NumberFormatInfo?

How come this is not working?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `The NumberDecimalDigits property is used with the "F" and "N" standard format strings without a precision specifier in numeric formatting operations.`  I don't believe it applies to your situation.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits.aspx)

Comment: It's for formatted output, it wont truncate the value in-situ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just want to truncate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.truncate.aspx

```
var myNumber = "100255.123";

var noDecimals = decimal.Truncate(decimal.Parse(myNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on decimals then can do something like

```
decimal.Floor(decimal.Parse(myNumber));
```

otherwise just hard cast to int

```
(int)decimal.Parse(myNumber)
```

Comment: `Floor()` isn't going to work as expected for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think NumberFormatInfo applies in your situation. It's normally used to format decimals into strings.

What's wrong with

```
var noDecimals = decimal.Round(decimal.Parse(myNumber, numberFormatInfo),0);
```